# Replace null values in pandas data frame column with 2D np.zeros() array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Assume the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': vals})
df['val'][[0, 3]] = np.nan
```

Gives:

```
    val
0   NaN
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   5.0
```

I need to be able to replace `NaN` values in the `val` column with a 2D numpy array of zeros. When I do the following:

```
z = np.zeros((10, 10))

df['val'][df['val'].isnull()] = z
```

The arrays are converted to scalars of value 0.0:

```
    val
0   0.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   0.0
4   5.0
```

I really need the array to be maintained (in this case, each `NaN` value - rows 0 and 3 from the original data frame -
should be replaced with a 10x10 array of zeros). I've tried converting to `object` type first

```
df = df.astype(object)
df['val'][df['val'].isnull()] = z
```

With no success. Whhyyyyy

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the example, right?

Comment: So for 0 in `val`, do you want the 0th array of `z`, and for 3 in `val`, you want the 3rd item from `z`?

Comment: See my very simple answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cause by the object data type we have a way with `fillna`

```
df.val.fillna(dict(zip(df.index[df['val'].isnull()],[z]*df['val'].isnull().sum())),inplace=True)
df
                                                 val
0  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
1                                                2.0
2                                                3.0
3  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
4                                                5.0
```

Comment: Almost, but this replaces values with an array of shape `(10,)`. I really need it to be replaced with `z`, which is shape `(10,10)` - a 2d array. Try `df['val'][0].shape`

Comment: @JmeCS check the update

Comment: Many thanks! This is gnarly. Really unclear to my why it drops the array structure to a scalar in the first place...

Comment: @JmeCS check my answer. It's simpler, and it might work for you.

Comment: @richardec I upvoted it but it doesn't work for my real-world problem unfortunately. Not clear why. It's too complicated to replicate here but your solution definitely works for the dummy problem.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. Change the dataframe's dtype to `object` and change `= z` to `= [z]`:

```
df = df.astype(object)
df.loc[df['val'].isna(), 'val'] = [z]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                 val
0  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
1                                                2.0
2                                                3.0
3  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
4                                                5.0
```